# Generalized Young symmetrizers, why not?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

For $n$ a positive integer, let $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Consider two set partitions $\mathcal{A}=\{A_1,\ldots,A_p\}$ and $\mathcal{B}=\{B_1,\ldots,B_q\}$ of the set $[n]$.
We will denote by $G(\mathcal{A})$ the Young subgroup of permutations $\sigma$ of $[n]$ which preserve the blocks of $\mathcal{A}$ (i.e., satisfy $\sigma(A_i)\subset A_i$ for all $i$), and similarly for $\mathcal{B}$.

We will say that $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are transverse iff for all $i,j$, the set $A_i\cap B_j$ has at most one element. Now define the group algebra element
$$
Y_{\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}}=\left(\sum_{\sigma\in G_{\mathcal{A}}}\sigma\right)\times
\left(\sum_{\rho\in G_{\mathcal{B}}}{\rm sgn}(\rho)\ \rho\right)\ .
$$

These elements generalize the Young symmetrizers, the latter corresponding to the *greedy* case where, given $\mathcal{A}$, the blocks of $\mathcal{B}$ are as big as allowed by transversality?

**Q1:** Has there been a systematic study of these more general group algebra elements?

**Q2:** If not, why not?

Of course, with hindsight, one could say the interesting pairs of transverse partitions are the greedy ones (i.e., corresponding to rows and columns of a Young tableau), because they successfully explain the representation theory of the symmetric group. I am looking more for a reason to a priori predict this success, like: "among all pairs of transvers set partitions, the greedy ones exactly are the ones such that $Y_{\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}}$ satisfies magic property $X$".

I was trying to read Young's QSA 1 article, and his definition comes out of the blue in Section 15.

**Q3:** Does anyone have any clue as to how Young got there?

Comment: Q1: Ricky Ini Liu's thesis https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/60196 comes to mind.

Comment: Possibly related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254782/a-schur-positivity-conjecture-related-to-row-and-column-permutations

Comment: Thanks to both. I did not know about the terminology of general "diagram" and hence did not know what to google. Indeed, this is exactly the situation I am describing with general transverse pairs of set partitions. So Q1's answer is yes, although perhaps the relevant literature might be a bit small. My question about property $X$ still stands as well as Q3.

Comment: I suppose that in the extreme case when $\mathcal{B}$ is made of singletons, the left ideal is a Young module which has been studied before.

Comment: An interesting case is when $D$ is the Rothe diagram of a permutation: then you get the corresponding Stanley symmetric function out: see https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01229705/document.

Comment: I should have added that Ricky Liu's thesis is interesting for giving some results on the general case, but much more has been done in some more restrictive situations, such as the "%-avoiding diagrams" of Shimozono and Reiner. I would love to see an actual text (as opposed to a bunch of papers) exposing this material.

Comment: I deleted a comment about Q3 because I realized now that you're asking specifically- how did Young know to use partition diagrams as opposed to others. Again, extremely naive answer, but: he knew the irreps had to be indexed by partitions, right?

Comment: @SamHopkins: "he knew the irreps had to be indexed by partitions,right?" probably not for $S_n$ since he was not really following the work of Frobenius, but for GL_n certainly since they were figured out by Clesbch in 1872 https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN250442582_0017?tify=%7B%22pages%22:[167],%22view%22:%22toc%22%7D